# How to access a multilevel Pandas Dataframe in Python - Storing Bloomberg data in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have installed Bloomberg API and pdblp library. I am able to get historical data and store it in Dataframe. But i am not sure how to access data from multilevel dataframe.

```
 import pdblp
 import pandas as pd

 con = pdblp.BCon(debug=True, port=8194)
 con.start()

 start = datetime.datetime.strptime("19800101", '%Y%m%d').strftime("%Y%m%d")
 end = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")


  df = pd.DataFrame(con.bdh('SPY US Equity',['PX_LAST', 'VOLUME'],start, end))
  print(df)
```

I am not able access the date column in Dataframe. Can anyone please help me.
If i try -- df.columns i am getting below output:

```
   MultiIndex(levels=[['SPY US Equity'], ['PX_LAST', 'VOLUME']],
       labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]],
       names=['ticker', 'field'])
```

Below is the data from Dataframe

```
 ticker     SPY US Equity             
field            PX_LAST       VOLUME
date                                 
1993-01-29       43.9375    1003200.0
1993-02-01       44.2500     480500.0
1993-02-02       44.3438     201300.0
1993-02-03       44.8125     529400.0
1993-02-04       45.0000     531500.0
1993-02-05       44.9688     492100.0
1993-02-08       44.9688     596100.0
1993-02-09       44.6563     122100.0
1993-02-10       44.7188     379600.0
1993-02-11       44.9375      19500.0
1993-02-12       44.5938      42500.0
1993-02-16       43.4688     374800.0
1993-02-17       43.4375     210900.0
1993-02-18       43.4063     378100.0
1993-02-19       43.5625      34900.0
1993-02-22       43.7188     513600.0
1993-02-23       43.6875     373700.0
1993-02-24       44.2500      26300.0
1993-02-25       44.3438      44500.0
1993-02-26       44.4063      66200.0
1993-03-01       44.2813      66500.0
1993-03-02       44.9375     182400.0
```

df.index gives below result:

```
       DatetimeIndex(['1993-01-29', '1993-02-01', '1993-02-02', '1993-02-03',
           '1993-02-04', '1993-02-05', '1993-02-08', '1993-02-09',
           '1993-02-10', '1993-02-11',
           ...
           '2017-07-13', '2017-07-14', '2017-07-17', '2017-07-18',
           '2017-07-19', '2017-07-20', '2017-07-21', '2017-07-24',
           '2017-07-25', '2017-07-26'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=6168, freq=None)
```

df.loc['1993-02-22'] gives following result:

```
  ticker         field  
  SPY US Equity  PX_LAST        43.7188
                 VOLUME     513600.0000
```

Comment: what does `df.index` show? it looks like `date` is your index, if so do `df.loc['1993-02-22']` as an example

Comment: Updated the Question with df.index and df.loc['1993-02-22'] result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'date' is in your index.  Pull it out with `reset_index`.

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Now, you can see your 'date' column using:

```
df['date']
```

Comment: Thanks! Its working fine. A followup question - I am using this values to draw charts using Plotly. I am getting  Keyerror:'Plotly_domain' if give following code `data = [go.Scatter(x=df['date'], y=df.iloc[:,1)]` How to resolve

Comment: @ArvinthKumar I am not familiar with Plotly.  Please start a separate question to get more help.

Comment: Okie. Thanks.. No Prob

Answer (score 2):

The `date` column is not a column, it's the `index` or row labels.

You access it via the `index` attribute

```
df.index
```